# aSmack crashes with NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, asmack

I apologize for the formatting in advance.
I am new-ish to android development and I am working on an XMPP Client to talk to a server at the house to do commands via Google talk bots....

1. I did look at stackoverflow for some answers and googled some answers
2. I updated to latest ASMACK lib via github
3. I did add the uses permission
4. I got ASMACK to work on a test app on my android.

I copied the working code to my application I am trying to make and gives me errors... like I said I am new and haven't done java programming in 10 years.. i don't know how to heard the error stack

I have a dialog with settings called 'Setting Dialog'. when I click the button I run this:

```
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    getWindow().setFlags(4, 4);
    setTitle("XMPP Settings");
    Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String host = HOST_ADDRESS;
                int port = HOST_PORT_NUM;
                String service = HOST_SERVICE;
                String username = "me@gmail.com";//getText(R.id.userid);
                String password = "abc123";//getText(R.id.password);

                // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
                XMPPConnection XMPPCon = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
                try 
                {
                    XMPPCon.connect();
                    XMPPCon.login(username,password);

                } 
                catch (XMPPException ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    HomeBotClient.setConnection(null);
                }
                HomeBotClient.setConnection(XMPPCon);
                dismiss();
            }

    }
    );
}
```

That calls this a function "setConnection" in the main activity

`public void setConnection (XMPPConnection XMPPCon) 
    {`

```
    this.XMPPCon = XMPPCon;
    if (XMPPCon != null) 
    {
        ChatManager chatmanager = XMPPCon.getChatManager();
        Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("psun03@gmail.com",new MessageListener()
        {
            public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                try 
                {
                  Log.v(TAG, "Got:" + message.getBody());
                  chat.sendMessage(message.getBody());
                } 
                catch (XMPPException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Couldn't respond:" + e);
                }
                Log.v(TAG, message.toString());
              }
        });
        try 
        {
            newChat.sendMessage("OMNOMNOM");
        } 
        catch (XMPPException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "couldn't send:" + e.toString());
        }

          // Accept only messages from friend@gmail.com
          PacketFilter filter 
              = new AndFilter(new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class), 
                              new FromContainsFilter("psun03@gmail.com"));

          // Collect these messages
          PacketCollector collector = XMPPCon.createPacketCollector(filter);

          while(true) {
            Packet packet = collector.nextResult();

            if (packet instanceof Message) 
            {
              Message msg = (Message) packet;
              // Process message
              Log.v(TAG, "Got message:" + msg.getBody());
            }
          }
    }
}
```

I get this error when I push the button

`04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.DirectSocketFactory.createSocket(DirectSocketFactory.java:49)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:576)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1034)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.ps.homebotclient.SettingsDialog$1.onClick(SettingsDialog.java:53)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-07 17:21:15.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: needed to start a new thread... got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs only when you try to invoke long-running process like web service call on main UI Thread. It works best in <2.3 devices but it will give you NetworkOnMainThreadException if you haven't included it in Threading and trying to run it on >3.0 devices.

To resolve it you can implement AsyncTask (a standard way) or include below code (lazy way):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Check and read more about NetworkOnMainThreadException at: [Android StrictMode – NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/02/22/android-strictmode-networkonmainthreadexception/)

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.0 or higher does not allow network I/O operations in a GUI thread, it will throw a `NetworkOnMainThread` Exception if you do so. In order to prevent this, aSmack comes with [AndroidConnectionConfiguration](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/static-src/custom/org/jivesoftware/smack/AndroidConnectionConfiguration.java), which provides

- `AndroidConnectionConfiguration(String serviceName)`
- `AndroidConnectionConfiguration(String serviceName, int timeout)`
- `AndroidConnectionConfiguration(String host, int port, String name)`

which, when used, will spawn a new thread and therefore prevent the Exception.